# How to publish magento website?

Tags: magento, web, web-deployment

I Develop one website using magento. How to i Publish on server? If asp.net after publishing
codes are converted into dll . but here magento How It work? How i configure my own website?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to do this. From simplest to most complex:

- Simple zip and unpack on the server. Migrate databases with mysqldumps.
- Push files with an FTP program. Preferably one with a compare viewer, such as Beyond Compare
- If you utilize a QA environment or a staging site on the same box or a local server you can utilize `rsync` to push changes from one directory to another.
- Create a source-control repository and use your production site root as a checkout of your Magento application (probably your best bet for ease of use).
- Utilize source-control but deploy with a build tool such as Apache Ant.
- Implement continuous integration with a tool such as Capistrano, Hudson/Jenkins, or CruiseControl

You really want to be using source control anyhow - so deploying straight from SVN/Git/Hg or another tool makes the most sense as it is easiest to manage and requires very little effort on your part. Making your repository publicly accessible can be as easy as using a free service such as GitHub or Beanstalkapp. Paid levels give you private repos or more than one user.

Continuous integration will be your best bet for rapid deployment on a site that is changing quickly and many deployments happen daily. Some comparison of tools:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Continuous_Integration_Software

I hope that helps. I have deployed Magento using all of the above methods. There really is no elegant way to push databases around outside of using upgrade scripts in local modules. You can use tools like Maatkit to diff tables or in some extreme situations I've seen developers alternate between qa and production environments using Magento's built-in table prefixes.